# Save web page and associated files separately (Just like on Windows)

Tags: safari

I am a previous windows user and I try to continue my work on a Mac.
My dilemma now is how to simply save a web page as html and all associated files in a separate folder.

This was easy in Windows. 
When I saved a web page I got the option to Save entire web page.
It downloaded an HTML file and created a folder with the same name as the file with added "-files".
All associated files like images, stylesheet and some javascript were downloaded in that folder.

I like this way because I have then a total control of the downloaded web page to add a note or elements as I chose to.
More plus, if I save multiple web pages from the same web site, all images that are the same (like layout) will only replace the older images (as long as they have the same file name). So the size will not increase as much. The "-files" folder will only increase with new article images.

On a Mac - Safari only have two options....
Save source or webarchive.
Webarchive is not edit-friendly

Anyone got a tip or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/). It does like you suggest when you choose "Web Page, Complete" on saving a page. It saves an HTML file and then all the associated in a folder with a similar name.

Comment: Hi Alistair. 
Yea I guess you are right. It works with Chrome. Was hoping I could use Safari only.